# Clicking this anchor to generate popup - magnific popup js

Tags: javascript, jquery, magnific-popup

I have multiple elements on the page with the data-attribute

```
data-lightbox="image"
```

HTML looks like

```
<div class="image isotope-item" id="image_72">
  <div class="work-item">
    <div class="dima-masonry-100"></div>
      <img src="/path/to/img" alt="Valley" />
      <div class="link_overlay">
        <ul class="icons-media">
          <li>
            <a data-lightbox="image" href="/path/to/img">
              <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
            </a>
         </li>
         <li>
           <a href="/images/72"><i class='fa fa-credit-card'></i></a>
         </li>
       </ul>
        <div class="work-info">
          <div class="work-title text-center">
            <p>Random Valley 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="topaz-hover"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="image isotope-item ok-md-3 ok-xsd-6 ok-sd-6 PlacesOfInterest" id="image_71">
  <div class="work-item">
    <div class="dima-masonry-100"></div>
      <img src="/path/to/img" alt="Usk" />
        <div class="link_overlay">
          <ul class="icons-media">
            <li>
              <a data-lightbox="image" href="/path/to/img">
                <i class="fa fa-link"></i>
              </a>
            </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/images/71"><i class='fa fa-credit-card'></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="work-info">
          <div class="work-title text-center">
            <p>Usk Valley 3</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <span class="topaz-hover"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So to get magnific popup to work I can do

```
// Portfolio Lightbox
$(function(){
  if($('body').hasClass('pages portfolio')){
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = $('[data-lightbox="image"]');
    i.magnificPopup({
     type: 'image',
     closeOnContentClick: !0,
     closeBtnInside: !1,
     fixedContentPos: !0,
     mainClass: "mfp-zoom-in",
     image: {
       verticalFit: !0
     }
  });
 }
});
```

But I also load extra images via an AJAX call and so need to use event delegation for dynamically created elements

So I have changed the code to

```
// Portfolio Lightbox
$(function(){
  if($('body').hasClass('pages portfolio')){
    $(document).on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var d = $('[data-lightbox="image"]');
      d.magnificPopup({
       type: 'image',
       closeOnContentClick: !0,
       closeBtnInside: !1,
       fixedContentPos: !0,
       mainClass: "mfp-zoom-in",
       image: {
         verticalFit: !0
       }
     });
   });
  }
});
```

I am finding that I have to click the link twice sometimes for the event to fire. Also by using

```
var d = $('[data-lightbox="image"]');
```

I am selecting all these elements on the page, when what I think I should be doing is taking advantage of `$(this)` but cannot seem to get it working

logging objects

```
var d = $('[data-lightbox="image"]');
console.log(d);
[a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "[data-lightbox="image"]"]

var d = $(this);
console.log(d);
[document, context: document]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading images via ajax, you could use one delegated event handler.

For example, assuming all your images are loaded within DOM element with the class `.pages`

```
$(document).on('click', '.pages' , function(e) {
    //do stuff
})
```

Within the callback you have access to the event object and properties like target and delegateTarget.

More info http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/